# How to wrap the following variable in HTML tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this line of code used inside a function -

```
$html .= $my_theme['social-pinterest'];
```

I can get it to output raw (a url in this case), but how would I wrap this correctly in say a paragraph tag?

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted the full function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $html;`

can't be more simple..

or if $html is already displayed..

`$html .= "<p class=''>". $my_theme['social-pinterest'] . "</p>";`